# create photo slide using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using VS2010,C# to develop a small enterprise ASP.NET web app for a company, I've created a history page, and I'm going to develop a simple photo slide using JavaScript (no JQuery if possible), is there any ready-made library? something that displays small thumbnails of images and where users mouse overs each one, a bigger version of the image is displayed, how can I create or find such a tool?

thanks

Comment: Unless you don't want any extra interaction and simply want to swap the thumbnail for an enlarged version of the image (if you already have the file available), why not just simply use CSS?

Comment: it seems a good idea to use CSS, but is there any tips on how to use CSS? can you please give me a sample?

Comment: See my answer below for the easiest method

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is just a JavaScript wrapper (in essence), so you'll be bypassing some convenience it brings. that being said, they're are plenty of libs out there that do what you're axin'. Building your own wouldn't be that difficult either. Here are a couple things to think about (thinking first will save you from feeling dumb down the line!!)

There's not much magic here.. you'll simply want to look at the 'onmouseover || onclick' event, and when the thumbnail image is 'moused over || clicked', you'll need to get some base coordinates and then show a div with a larger image hovering over the smaller image ( you should use 2 images (one small, and one large) and you should probably create them on disk at upload or image creation (file streaming works too, but lacks efficiency if they're static images (cache?) how much time do you want to spend on it, lol).

To place the larger image's location correctly, you're either going to want to add a div dynamically who's content is the large image, or show / hide a hidden div which already has the larger image loaded (this way images could already be loaded, however it will load all even if not needed, again, how much time), you can hide these in the DOM somewhere. Then by setting the larger hovered images position to 'absolute', and most likely it's 'z-index' to the very front you can show the larger image on top of the thumbnail image.

You can use either the active smaller image location as the base coords, or the position of the mouse pointer relative to the div which is being 'moused over || clicked' depending on how you want your functionality to work

anyhow, like was said before, there are numerous lib's out there that will do exactly this. This has been desirable functionality for a long time and you will most likely be re-inventing the wheel.. However, there's nothing wrong with knowing how to create a wheel..

http://highslide.com/

http://www.admixweb.com/2010/03/08/how-to-create-a-fancy-image-gallery-with-css3/

google will help too: "pure javascript image sliders"

Comment: CSS will have it's limitations if you want to have a dynamic image slider, the problem with "hard-coding" the image path in CSS is that you'll have to "hard-code" every image path for every div you want..

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are plenty of ready solutions and you can of course build your own. The trick here is to assign DOM classes to large images and thumbnails and at the application start, show only first image. Then on the mouse over add a class to the second large image that will show  this one and to one that was visible before class that will hide it. As I said there are plenty of tutorials and ready scripts.

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/57-free-image-gallery-slideshow-and-lightbox-solutions/

http://www.ehow.com/how_6457406_javascript-gallery-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Javascript, if you have both the thumbnail file and the enlarged file (or perhaps the single file if it is initially large and you scale it down to create a thumbnail,) you can use CSS which would be a much more accessible solution as user-agents without Javascript will still be able to use the functionality. Such a solution also assumes you don't want any extra interaction apart from swapping the images.

To swap images with CSS it is best to have a container element for your image, such as a div (while not semantically correct, it makes this type of interaction easier):

```
<div id="thumbnail">
</div>

#thumbnail
{
  background-image:url("{URL to image, relative to the CSS}");
}
/*Use :hover pseudo-class to detect hover events*/
#thumbnail:hover
{
  background-image:url("{Replacement image URL}");
}
```

Note that the :hover pseudo-class does not work in IE6 unless applied to an anchor element, however it is rare to support IE6 these days, but still good to know.

Answer (score 0):

This might be help you.
Here is sample code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #nav
        {
            margin: 20px auto;
        }
        #nav a
        {
            padding: 4px 6px;
            margin: 3px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #ddd;
        }
        #nav a.activeSlide
        {
            color: #c00;
        }
        #nav a:focus
        {
            outline: none;
        }

        .slideshow
        {
            margin: 20px auto;
            padding: 0;
            clear: left;
        }
        .slide
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .slideshow, .slide
        {
            height: 232px;
            width: 710px;
        }
        .slideshow img
        {
            padding: 15px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            background-color: #eee;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(function () {
            $('#main').cycle({

                fx: 'cover',
                speed: 500,
                timeout: 2000

            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.slideshow').cycle({
                fx: 'scrollLeft',
                timeout: 0,
                pager: '#nav'
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Cover Effect</legend>
        <div id="main" style="width: 200px; height: 300px">
            <img src="Images/bamboo.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 300px" />
            <img src="Images/ceynote.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 300px" />
            <img src="Images/cypress.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 300px" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Grouping div</legend>
        <div style="margin: auto; text-align: center">
            <div id="nav">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="Images/firefox-512-200x200.png" width="200" height="200" />
                <img src="Images/iguana.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
                <img src="Images/josh-ships.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="Images/bamboo.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
                <img src="Images/ceynote.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
                <img src="Images/cypress.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="Images/jungle.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
                <img src="Images/palmtree.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
                <img src="Images/iguana.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You can download image slide show asp.net example from this link. [Click Here...](http://jayeshsorathia.blogspot.com/2013/02/image-slide-show-using-jquery-with-aspnet-example.html)